# Using Javascript, how can you allow page scroll while live data is pouring in?

Tags: javascript, twitter

Ok this is a really hard question to explain.

As an example, say you have terminal running a server. That server updates as things change and continues to scroll with each new line of information. However, if you want to scroll up to look at old data, you can. When you're done looking at the old data, you scroll back down and the new data continues to scroll the page up.

I have a twitter socket continually displaying tweets based on a keyword. I want to see every new tweet as they come in, but be able to scroll up to look at old tweets any time. How can I accomplish this with Javascript?

Here is my client side javascript:

```
// when tweeter event is received, add it to the page
socket.on('tweeter', function(data){
// console.log(data);
var d = new Date();
document.getElementById('stream').innerText += d.getHours() + ':' +   
                                d.getMinutes() + ' ' + data.text + '\n' + '\n';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you'll need the functionality to make the page focus on the latest data as it comes. Next, you'll need a variable that tells the focusing functionality to start or stop. Lastly, you'll need a scroll event handler that toggles that variable. If you scroll away from the data, it toggles the variable to stop following the data so you can scroll freely. If you scroll back to the latest data, it toggles it back to follow the data. The rest is math.

Comment: You hit it on the nail with that description. Now turning that pseudo-code into real code is the issue.